# Block data structure

Tags: blocks, block-header

Can someone explain the transaction_mroot, action_mroot and block_mroot used in block_header? I understand what a merkel tree is. Is transaction data actually stored in block or just the transaction hash stored in block?

```
   struct block_header
   {
      digest_type     digest() const;
      uint32_t        block_num() const { return num_from_id(previous) + 1; }
      static uint32_t num_from_id(const block_id_type& id);

      block_id_type                    previous;
      block_timestamp_type             timestamp;

      checksum256_type                 transaction_mroot; /// mroot of cycles_summary
      checksum256_type                 action_mroot;
      checksum256_type                 block_mroot;

      account_name                     producer;

      /** The producer schedule version that should validate this block, this is used to
       * indicate that the prior block which included new_producers->version has been marked
       * irreversible and that it the new producer schedule takes effect this block.
       */
      uint32_t                          schedule_version = 0;
      optional<producer_schedule_type>  new_producers;
   };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The `transaction_mroot` is the [Merkle root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) of the `transaction_receipts` included in the block.
- The `block_mroot` is not part of latest master (it is now implicit, factored into signature but not actually on the wire).
- The `action_mroot` creates a `mroot` over all dispatched actions that were evaluated while applying transactions in the block. It is used for IBC proofs and light/partial client validation.